# Is there any Way to Read 3D Pdf using Cordova/Hybrid App for tablets?

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have existed Cordova app available using Vue js 3.1.2
used Mozilla PDf.js for Displaying Pdf file,
But the problem is to read 3D pdf in that application.
Is it to possible to make 3d pdf reader Inbuilt?

I've tried 3d pdf Reader Android app from play store but you need to go out from the app and add pdf there and then it shows 3d pdf reader.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the mozilla PDF viewer with the Adobe.

Doc:
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_3d_api_reference.pdf

Comment: Can you give an example of how it can be used in js Or integrate into Cordova App, it would be more helpful.